# Find median of every row using matrixStats::rowMedians

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, median

I am trying to calculate the row median for a data frame `df` with `rowMedians` from `matrixStats` package.

```
Abundance Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4 Sample5 Sample6 Sample7
Species1   2        4       0       0       0       6       0
Species2   3        5       6       4       0       0       0
Species3   3        7       2       5       8       0       0
Species4   0        0       3       8       0       0       8
Species5   7        5       6       0       0       4       4
Species6   4        2       3       0       0       2       1
```

I want to calculate the median of every row and append them in a new column. I got an error

> Argument 'x' must be a vector or matrix

so I tried to convert my `df` to a matrix. The `str` function shows that every value for the species is numeric, so I tried:

```
library(matrixStats)
matrix(df, rownames.force = NA)
rowMedians(df)
```

but I am still getting the same error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: correct - I don't want the abundance column with the names in the calculation. And I have added the matrixStats to my question, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to include that `Abundance` column for median calculation. Let `df` be your current data frame.

```
library(matrixStats)
rowMedians(as.matrix(df[-1]))
```

---

A few comments besides the correct code above.

1. Have you checked what `matrix(df)` is?
2. Even if it correctly returns you a numeric matrix, it does not overwrite `df`. So `rowMedians(df)` gives you the same error as if nothing has happened;
3. As an exercise, compare `as.matrix(df[-1])` and `as.matrix(df)`.

Understanding these issues prevents you from getting errors in future.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to remove first column because it's not numeric :

```
df$median_score <- apply(df[,-1], 1, median)
```